# Auth::user() not working on redirect

Tags: php, laravel, slack-api, laravel-socialite

So currently I'm joining together two API services using Laravel Socialite. Both work fine on their own.

I want to make it so you can sign in using the 'add to Slack' button and it will store the Slack details on the `users` table without needing to bother storing things like name, email address, password etc. So far my schema looks like this:

- id
- slack_user_id
- slack_access_token
- slack_team_name
- slack_team_id
- slack_bot_user_id
- slack_bot_access_token
- Other fields for second API

I save the user and then manually authenticate them and redirect them to the dashboard like so:

```
  Auth::loginUsingId($user->id, true);
  return redirect('home');
```

Then I prompt them to connect to the next service. The OAuth flow on its own works perfectly, but I want to update the logged in user with the new details. My code looks like this:

```
 $id = Auth::user()->id;
 $user = User::findOrFail($id);
 //Save fields to the user
 $user->save();
 return redirect('/home');
```

This fails to work as it cannot find the user through `Auth`. I have tried to dump the current `Auth::user()` object but it returns null.

This works fine before the redirect to the OAuth provider but it looks like it's killing the session in between. I am currently using `file` as my session driver but have also tried using `cookie`.

Sample code of the second API code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Auth;
use App\User;
use Session;
use Socialite;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class OAuthController extends Controller
{
    public function handleProviderCallback(Request $request)
    {
        $stravaUser = Socialite::driver('strava')->stateless()->user();
        $accessTokenResponseBody = $stravaUser->accessTokenResponseBody;
        dd(\Auth::user());
        $id = Auth::user()->id;
        $user = User::findOrFail($id);
        //Do User fields here
        $user->save();
        return redirect('/home');
    }
}
```

Any advice?

Comment: do you get any error from `Auth::user()` ?

Comment: It simply returns `null`

Comment: what about `\Auth::user()` ?

Comment: That also returns null.

Comment: Where you are using this code in which file controller share that also ?

Comment: If I have understood you correctly, I'm using this code in a standalone controller which has a single function which is using Socialite to handle the Callback from the API Provider. I've also ensured that I have `use Auth;` in the head of the file. Sample code above.

Comment: in API `Auth` will not work, API works with auth token

Comment: @C2486 That makes sense. In which case, what is the recommended way that I find the correct user and store the new details?

Comment: Your can use laravel passport, or jwtauth.

Comment: Just to clarify, I'm not actually creating an API, simply consuming some OAuth data from Laravel Socialite. Wouldn't passport / jwtauth be inappropriate in this case?

Comment: No, In your controller you should get `Auth` if there is no session issue.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the route is going through an auth middleware... something like this

```
Route::middleware( [ 'auth' ] )->group( function () {
    Route::get( '/home', 'SomeController@someFunction' );
} );
```

Comment: Just tried adding both '/home' and the OAuth `handleProviderCallback` controller function into an auth middleware with no luck :/